# glGetBufferSubData returns the same data between two iterations of glDrawTransformFeedback()

Tags: opengl

I try to build a OpenGL program that do the Newton-Raphson method for five values at the same time. Actually, I just want to learn how to use TRANSFORM FEEDBACK

The vertex Shader just passes the value to geometry Shader

```
const GLchar* vertexShaderSrc = R"glsl(
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in float result;
layout (location = 1) in float val;
layout (location = 2) in float iterTime;
layout (location = 3) in float type;

out float geoResult;
out float geoVal;
out float geoIterTime;
out float geoType;

void main()
{
    geoResult = result;
    geoVal =  val;
    geoIterTime = iterTime;
    geoType = type;
})glsl";
```

The Geometry Shader creates five new value to buffer and cached by transform feedback at the first time. Then, the program makes iteration for five values.

```
const GLchar* geometryShaderSrc = R"glsl(
#version 330 core
layout(points) in;
layout(points,max_vertices=100) out;

#define START_POINT 1.0f
#define REST_POINT 2.0f

in float geoResult[];
in float geoVal[];
in float geoIterTime[];
in float geoType[];

out float outResult;
out float outVal;
out float outIterTime;
out float outType;

void main(){
    if(geoType[0] == START_POINT){
        for(int i = 1; i<=5; ++i){
            outResult = geoVal[0]/2;
            outVal = geoVal[0]+50*i;
            outIterTime = geoIterTime[0];
            outType = REST_POINT;
            EmitVertex();
        }
        EndPrimitive();
    }
    else{
        outResult = geoResult[0]/2 +  geoVal[0] / geoResult[0]/2;
        outVal = geoVal[0];
        outIterTime = geoIterTime[0] - 1;
        outType = REST_POINT;
        EmitVertex();
        EndPrimitive();
    }
} )glsl";
```

The loop is as follow

```
while (iterTimeCount-->0)
{

    glEnable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);
    // specify VBO and TFO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, nodeBuffer[currVB]);
    glBindTransformFeedback(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, transformFeedback[currTFB]);



    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);


    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(resolveNode), (const GLvoid*) 0);  // result
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(resolveNode), (const GLvoid*) 4);  // val
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(resolveNode), (const GLvoid*) 8);  // iterTime
    glVertexAttribPointer(3, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(resolveNode), (const GLvoid*) 12); // type

    glBeginTransformFeedback(GL_POINTS);

    // specially do drawing for the first particle. the rest of the particles will be
    // create and drawn by TransformFeedback
    if (isFirst) {
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);

        isFirst = false;
    }
    else {
        glDrawTransformFeedback(GL_POINTS, transformFeedback[currVB]);
    }

    glEndTransformFeedback();

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(3);

    glGetBufferSubData(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER,
                       0, sizeof(feedback), feedback);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        printf("%f\t%f\t%f\t| ",feedback[i].result,feedback[i].val,feedback[i].iterTime);
    }

    printf("\n\n");


    // switch VBO and TBO
    currVB = currTFB;
    currTFB = (currTFB + 1) & 0x1;
}
```

focus on **feedback[i].iterTime** ,  I get 10 10 8 8 6 6 4 4 2 2 0 , which should be 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0. Amazing...

Comment: Assuming your logic is right have you tried putting glFlush() before your call to glGetBufferSubData()?

Comment: I have tried to use glFlush() function. But I get the same result. Be more clearly, I use two vertex buffer object and two transform buffer object for my work. The 2rd transform feedback will caches data from 1st geometry shader, then next time 2rd transform feedback sends the data from its buffer to 2rd vertex shader for computing. And so on ....... it is wired to see 10 10 8 8 6 6... I sure I have switch the transform buffer every time according to the  last several lines.

Comment: I mostly suspect you are having some synchronisation issue. Calling glEndTransformFeedback() before reading back data from transform feedback buffer will make sure its in safe state but you have to be sure you are doing that for both buffers ypu are using